# Powershell remoting session is not getting establish

Tags: powershell, remoting, powershell-remoting

I am trying to create remote session between two machines. Say Machine A and Machine B.But I am not able to establish the connection.
However, if i try to set remote session from Machine B to Machine A. I can. I am even able to execute commands from B on A.
I can connect Machine B from Machine C and vice versa. This machine C can connect with Machine A as well, just like Machine B but Machine A can not create remote session with Machine C. So here is the equation:

Machine A-> Machine B = No

Machine B-> Machine A = Yes

Machine B-> Machine C = Yes

Machine C-> Machine A = Yes

Machine C-> Machine B = Yes

Now all three machines are virtual machine, so hosting environment is same (except B is windows server 2008).
 Window remote management service is running on all three. User we are using has admin rights on all three

Howevere, i can run Get-Process, Get-Culture all such commands from Machine A to Machine B, e.g.

Get-EventLog -ComputerName Machine B (following by log name, say windows powershell and i can see the output).

Is there something i am missing?
Please help.

Regards,
Monica

Comment: What error are you getting? If you got a message along the lines of "look here to troubleshoot", which you should have, did you check all the instructions there?

Comment: I am getting connection to specified remote was refused. I checked service, trusted hosts (value is *), i have executed below mentioned command as well with Machine B as remote......winrm s winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="Machine B"}'.................i have noticed one thing. On Machine A....powershell is 2012. But on B and C, its 2009.....can that be the reason?

Comment: Test-WSMan? have you tried that? From A to B. Also, does all of the machines have PowerShell x64?

Comment: Executed....still same error. I think only A is 64 bit...coz when i ran [Environment]::Is64BitProcess on A...it gives True.....on other two...nothing. Can this be the reason?

Comment: I have upgraded powershell version on Machine B to 3.0 from 2.0, to match with Machine A powershell version (also 3.0). But still remote session is not getting established from A to B. Other way is still working. (B to A)

Comment: Maybe with invoke?
invoke-command {get-eventlog -LogName System} -ComputerName <ServerName>

Comment: I tried the same but still same output. I have shifted my work to Machine C now to get it done but it seems some error with compatibility of versions...maybe

Comment: I am facing another issue, while i can execute most of the commands i wanted to but strangely few commands are not giving expected result. For example, i have installed NodeJs on machine B and trying to access it through powershell from Machine C but not able it. If i to execute npm from command prompt on machine B (after setting path variable) it gives output but on machine C, through powershell same command is throwing error.......any idea why?